# ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per data set. 4462 data sets and 1 colors were provided

Tags: python, valueerror

I have an error that I do not comprehend, am quite new to this so thank you all in advance!
I am using Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda3)[The link here shows my code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyjAb.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the *dimensionality* of your `all_unbalanced_data` array/list.

If you are using an N-dimensional data (N different datasets, lists of data, etc) as input to `plt.hist`, then the `color` kwarg must be of the same *dimensionality*.

You input one single color, so for the script to work your data must be shaped as a 1-dimensional array.

### A rule of thumb

Suppose your data are contained in a numpy array:

```
all_unbalanced_data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Than you can extract the shape (*dimensionality*) of the array:

```
all_unbalanced_data.shape
>>> (2, 4)
```

The the number of colors `plt.hist` will expect will be 2:

```
color = ['color_code_1', 'color_code_2']
```

So in your case `plt.hist` is expecting 4462 different colors.